# SQL Server grant EXECUTE permission to user from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I have `DatabaseA` and `DatabaseB`. In `DatabaseA` is `UserA`, in `DatabaseB` is `UserB`.

`UserA` has permission to `EXECUTE` scalar function `FunctionA` in `DatabaseA`, `UserB` has permission to `EXECUTE` stored procedure `ProcedureB` in `DatabaseB`.

Now `ProcedureB` uses `FunctionA`, so when `UserB` executes `ProcedureB`, he gets error

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object FunctionA

But when I'm trying to grant him permission with

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON DatabaseA.schema.FunctionA TO UserB
```

I get another error:

> Cannot find the user UserB, because it does not exist or you do not have permission

How to fix this? Is there a way of executing `FunctionA` inside `ProcedureB` with privileges of `UserA`? Or grant execute permission to `UserB` in some other manner?

Answer (score 0):

You're close! The error message is telling you that UserB doesn't exist in DatabaseA, so you need to create it. Once you do, you should be able to grant the permission and everything should work.

Comment: But if I will create UserB on DatabaseA that user will be the same user as UserB on DatabaseB? I mean won't I get error like "UserB (from DatabaseB) is not the same as UserB (from DatabaseA)? And how to create UserB on DatabaseA? 'CREATE USER UserB FOR LOGIN XYZ;' ?

Comment: Users are database scoped objects. Just like you can have a stored procedure with the same name in multiple databases, so to can you have a user with the same name in multiple databases. In you case, you'll need to have a user that maps to the same login in both databases. If UserB is mapped to login XYZ in DatabaseA, it will need that same mapping in DatabaseB.